# While loop not functioning on assigning char '\0'

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I've tried this program but it doesn't work, IMO it should've stored **q** at every position on the array, but why is it not happening?

```
  `
   int main()
   {
      char *c=new char[10];
      char *p=c+9;
      *p='\0';    //This should've assigned the last value to null terminator
      int i=0;
      p=c;
      while(*c)
        {
            i++;
            *c='q';
            cout<<*c<<endl;
            ++c;
        }
      cout<<i<<endl<<*p<<endl;
      return 0;
  }
```

This is really beyond me, please help. Why this loop is not looping for 10 times? It should as the '\0'is at the 10th position.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: It is printing 0 (for i) and then nothing except a newline.

Comment: Just look what `while(*c)` does. You probably meant `while(i<9)`

Comment: @MarekVitek no, that works fine, try this then you'll find: 
char *c ="hello";
while(*c){ \\do something
++c;     }

Comment: Yes, but it means that you have zero value at the end of the hello string. In your code you have nothing so it is either all zeros and thus ending on first character or some garbage with unexpected results. See what @Rick Astley wrote.

Comment: If you want to see what is going on, then look at `c` in the debugger just right after it's declaration. Or just try to print it out. Just because you set null terminator at the end with `*p='\0';` it doesn't mean it can't be anywhere else. In fact you can have array/string full of null terminators. Sometimes it is used as fast way to shorten string. Just put a `\0` where new end should be.

Comment: Use std::string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask for 10 `chars` by `new` and then you try to go over these chars with `while(*c)` but since you never initialize this memory block you already have undefined behavior in the first place when you dereference it through `*c`.

To explain this situation though, there's a good chance you're running this in debug mode in which case there's a good chance that everything returned from `new` is zeroed out memory (the debugger wants to be nice), which means that your `while` loop will terminate immediately. Use a `for` loop instead or explicitly loop until a certain number.

Comment: Never lettin us down.

Comment: I.e. this is *undefined behavior* (might be worth mentioning).

Comment: @Rick Can you please explain what debug mode and what is zeroed out memory?

Comment: @BenSteffan Thanks, added.

Comment: @infinite You usually have debug and release mode, release mode is with optimizations and no help to remove bugs, debug is the complete opposite. Zeroed out memory is memory that is `memset` with all zeroes.

Comment: @Rick just one more query: can't we initialize the char array as we do with int array like this :  int *I = new int[10](); //initializing ints to 0